# I am getting IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed: login_new_user.sturesidance

Tags: django, forms, view, model, bootstrap-5

In my template I have defined it like this,

`

```
<!-- residance -->
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 ">
                        <span class="input-group-text w-25" for="residance">Residence</span>
                        <input class="form-control text-bg-primary bg-opacity-10 text-dark text-opacity-50"
                            type="textarea" name="stureisidance" cols="4" rows="5" placeholder="type current address"
                            required>
                    </div>
```

`

In my models i have this filed .

`

```
 sturesidance=models.TextField()
```

`
This is how I created my object,

`

```
new_user.objects.create( stuname= stuname, stubirthday= stubirthday, stuphoto= stuphoto , stugemail= stugemail ,stugrade= stugrade , stuclass=  stuclass,stuentrance= stuentrance , sturesidance= sturesidance ,stuguardian= stuguardian , stugtele= stugtele , stumother= stumother ,stumothertele= stumothertele ,stuotherskills= stuotherskills ,stucertificate= stucertificate ,stuletter= stuletter ,stumedical= stumedical ,stusports= stusports ,stupassword= stupassword )
```

`

Now I am getting error
IntegrityError
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: login_new_user.sturesidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the field's name in html code. It seems to be different from the name of the field defined in Model.

```
In html - stureisidance
In model - sturesidance
```

Once you make it identical, it might work.